# sparklyr Finding a way to work with timeseries (hts, forecast, timekit or prophet)

Tags: apache-spark, time-series, sparklyr

```
> data2_tbl <- copy_to(sc, FB_tbl) #sc as spark connection
> idx <- tk_index(data2_tbl)

Warning message:
In tk_index.default(data2_tbl) :
  `tk_index` is not designed to work with objects of class tbl_spark.
```

I have a couple of questions to the group:

1. Does `sparklyr` have support on time series like they have on the other ml_* algorithms?
2. We also tried and found the spark-ts package that supports time series in Spark. 
   I have not found good materials on how to use it. Does anyone have some documentations or experience on this?

Answer (score 2):

> Does sparklyr have support on time series like they have on the other ml_* algorithms?

It doesn't, because Spark doesn't. All `ml_` or `ft_` methods are just simple wrappers around corresponding Spark algorithms.

> We also tried and found the spark-ts package that supports time series in Spark.

At this moment there is no actively developed, open source, times series analysis tool for Spark. Both `spark-timeseries` and `flint` don't seem to be maintained anymore.

This partially reflects Spark computing model, which is a poor fit for time series processing. Expressing sequential relationships in Spark is hard and usually expensive, and many time series analysis techniques, are just a bad fit for distributed processing due to their global dependencies.